# Hebrew and numbers

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database and use it with phpMyAdmin, and values in one of the fields are mixed hebrew letters with numbers like :

> אב12

first character is א
second character is ב
third character is 1
fourth character is 2

The above is written in correctly, though this value:

first character is 1
second character is 2
third character is א
fourth character is ב

looks the same here and in the database

Is it possible to make it look different?
PS. hebrew is right to left

Comment: אני לא כל כך ברור על השאלה שלך

Comment: to blockhead:  אני רוצה שבבסיס הנתונים שני המחרוזות יראו שונה: אב12 12אב

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact changing the phpMyAdmin language to hebrew helped. Not very comfortable though(

Answer (score 0):

As a native Hebrew speaker, I find it less confusing, and always have some handy tools.

a. You can use the mouse to select the text to discover its ordering. If you'd start the selection from the line above the code you'll be able to see that Hebrew letter alef (`א`) is actually the first character on that line, Hebrew letter bet (`ב`) is the second, and the third and forth places are the numerics, as expected.

b. You can also switch the text direction to RTL and be able to see it in the right order from Right to Left. While you could do it easily in HTML page, it takes few minutes to compose a test page. Faster solution could be to paste the text into a text input, and switch the field directionality using Ctrl-Shift-X under Firefox, or Ctrl-Shift if you have access to Windows machine.